# Sticky footer not sticking

Tags: jquery, html, css, sticky-footer

Link to site: http://www.bigideaadv.com/xsp

I'm trying to get the footer to stick. Works okay in Firefox, not so in IE and Safari/Chrome. When the window gets too small, the footer switches from a fixed position to a more fluid one that is supposed to rest at the bottom of the page.

If you shorten the window and then scroll to the bottom of the page, then expand the page till the scrollbar ends, the footer sits about 50-100px above the bottom of the page. Does anyone know why this happens?

CSS:

```
    html, body {
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100%;
    }

    #wrap {
        min-height:100% !important;
    }

    #wrap:before { /* Opera and IE8 "redraw" bug fix */
        content:"";
        float:left;
        height:100%;
        margin-top:-999em;
    }

    #container {
        position: relative;
        /*margin: 72px 0 172px 0;*/
        top: 72px;
        bottom: 172px;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        overflow: auto;
    }

    #top_navigation {
        position: fixed;
        min-width: 1010px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 72px;
        background: url('../images/opaque.png') repeat;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        z-index: 2000;
    }

    #bottom_navigation {
        position: fixed;
        min-width: 1550px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 172px;
        background: url('../images/opaque.png') repeat;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
```

Javascript:

```
    int_window_width = $(window).width();
    int_window_height = $(window).height();

    if ((int_window_width <= int_min_window_width && int_window_height >= int_min_window_height) || int_window_height <= int_min_window_height) { 
        $('html').css('overflow-y', 'scroll');
        $('#bottom_navigation').css('bottom', '');
        $('#bottom_navigation').css('margin-top', '');
        $('#bottom_navigation').css('position', 'relative');
    }

    if ((int_window_width >= int_min_window_width && int_window_height >= int_min_window_height) || int_window_height >= int_min_window_height) { 
        $('html').css('overflow-y', 'hidden');
        $('#bottom_navigation').css('position', 'absolute');
        $('#bottom_navigation').css('top', '');
        $('#bottom_navigation').css('bottom', '0');
        $('#bottom_navigation').css('margin-top', '');
    }
```

Comment: Do mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/n6NQZ/ this one is fixed. Do you want to change it from fixed to absolute based on page scrolling?

Comment: @Jay, you know your demo won't work in IE6?

Comment: This one is working in IE6 as well: http://jsfiddle.net/NDC3L/

Comment: No no. The page footer changes it's properties based on size. So if the browser window is larger than a particular size, the footer is in the fixed position at the bottom, for all other cases, it should be absolute at the bottom of the page below the content. Link to follow: http://www.bigideaadv.com/xsp

Answer (score 1):

If you want the footer not to move when the document is scrolled, just use `position:fixed; bottom: 0`. IE6 doesn't support `position:fixed` so you'll need to apply a polyfill: http://www.css-101.org/fixed-positioning/05.php

Comment: That's answer won't fix my issue though. Based on the size of the browser window, the footer needs to be either fixed(larger sized window) or absolute bottom (smaller sized window). The jquery fires correctly if you close up the window past 619px high.

The issue arises if you scroll to bottom of the page, with footer absolutely positioned and you expand the window, the footer doesn't stick. It floats 50-100px above the bottom of the window. Link to follow: www.bigideaadv.com/xsp